# Dependency injection not working when overloading AddTransient with required classes in .NET Core

Tags: .net, mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

In startup class we added:

```
services.AddTransient<ITasksService, TasksService>(provider => MultiTenentDB<TeamService>(provider));

private T MultiTenentDB<T>(IServiceProvider provider)
{
        IServiceScope scope = provider.CreateScope();
        AppTenant appTenent = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<AppTenant>();

        if (appTenent == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Organization id required");

        string connectionString = string.Format(appTenent.MongoDbServer.ConnectionString);
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        string database = "";

        if (_env.IsProduction())
        {
            database = appTenent.MongoDbServer.DatabaseProd;
        }
        else  
        {
            database = appTenent.MongoDbServer.Database;
        }

        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { mongoClient, database });
    }
```

In TaskService:

```
public class TasksService : ITaskService
{
    public readonly ISendEmailService _SendemailService;
    public readonly IEmailBodyService _emailBodyService;
    private IMongoCollection<TasksModel> _task;

    public TasksService(IMongoClient client, string database) 
    {
        _database = client.GetDatabase(database);
        _task = _database.GetCollection<TasksModel>("Tasks");
    }

    public TasksService(  ISendEmailService SendemailService, IEmailBodyService emailBodyService)
    {
        _SendemailService = SendemailService;
        _emailBodyService = emailBodyService;
    }
}
```

> TasksService(  ISendEmailService SendemailService, IEmailBodyService
> emailBodyService)

is not firing due to overloading of the transient in the startup class. How to fire both the constructors or any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Activator.CreateInstance`, you should instead use [`ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0), which allows you to inject services from the provider.

That way, you can have a single constructor:

```cs
public TasksService(  ISendEmailService SendemailService, IEmailBodyService emailBodyService, IMongoClient client, string database)
{
    _SendemailService = SendemailService;
    _emailBodyService = emailBodyService;
    
    _database = client.GetDatabase(database);
    _task = _database.GetCollection<TasksModel>("Tasks");
}
```

and then in `MultiTenentDB<T>` :

```cs
return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<T>(provider, mongoClient, database);
```

`ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` will call the appropriate constructor, with services `ISendEmailService` and `IEmailBodyService` injected from the service provider, while `IMongoClient client` and `string database` are the arguments of the call.